# Problem in changing alpha when clicking the radio button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a todo list app in android studio. When the task is checked as complete I want it to become dull and a strikethrough to appear on the text.

Strikethrough is working fine as when the button is clicked the effect appear based on whether the ischecked boolean is true or false but when I tried to the same with the dull affect by changing the cardView's alpha to 0.5 but it is not working. The effect appears and then disappears automatically but when I click on other tasks the affect appears.

`onBindViewHolder` function in my adapter class

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentTask = differ.currentList[position]

        holder.itemBinding.taskTextView.text = currentTask.taskTitle

        holder.itemBinding.radioButton.apply {
            isChecked = currentTask.isComplete

            setOnClickListener {
                val taskId = currentTask.id
                val isChecked = currentTask.isComplete
                tasksViewModel.updateTaskCompletionStatus(taskId, !isChecked)
            }
        }

        val isCompleted = currentTask.isComplete
        holder.itemBinding.taskTextView.paintFlags =
            if (isCompleted) {
                holder.itemBinding.cardViewAnim.alpha = 0.5f
                Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            } else{
                holder.itemBinding.cardViewAnim.alpha = 1.0f
                0
            }

        holder.itemBinding.taskTextView.invalidate()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val direction = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToUpdateTaskFragment(currentTask)
            it.findNavController().navigate(direction)
        }
    }
```

**HomeFragment** class `onViewCreated` method :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        tasksViewModel = (activity as MainActivity).tasksViewModel

        val userName = arguments?.getString("userName")
        if (!userName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            binding.userName.text = userName
        }

        setUpRecyclerView()

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_newTaskFragment)
        }

        // Observe task completion status change and update the adapter
        tasksViewModel.taskCompletionStatusUpdated.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(tasksViewModel,requireContext())

        binding.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = taskAdapter
        }

        activity.let {
            tasksViewModel.getAllTasks().observe(
                viewLifecycleOwner
            ) { task ->
                taskAdapter.differ.submitList(task)
                updateUI(task)
            }
        }

    }
```

**TaskViewHolder** Class

```
class TaskViewModel(app: Application, private val taskRepository: TaskRepository) : AndroidViewModel(app){


    private val _taskCompletionStatusUpdated = MutableLiveData<Unit>()
    val taskCompletionStatusUpdated: LiveData<Unit>
        get() = _taskCompletionStatusUpdated

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)

    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }

    fun addTask(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
        taskRepository.insertTask(task)
    }

    fun deleteTask(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
        taskRepository.deleteTask(task)
    }

    fun updateTask(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
        taskRepository.updateTask(task)
    }

    fun getAllTasks() = taskRepository.getAllTasks()

    fun updateTaskCompletionStatus(taskId: Int, completed: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        taskRepository.updateTaskCompletionStatus(taskId, completed)
        _taskCompletionStatusUpdated.postValue(Unit)
    }

}
```

[image: problem gif]